# Granting Editor rights in Outlook 2007 via Exchange Management Console?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, delegation

Am I missing something?

Do my individual users have to allow delegate access through the tools>options>delegates tab, or can I give individuals the rights to do so in EMC?

This is a new position for me, and I feel crazy for asking, but everyone is telling me that the previous person did it for them all the time.

More straight forward:

user A wants to view/add/edit things on user B's calendar.

Can I do this from the server, or do the users have to do it themselves in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the server, but its the hack way to do it. You really want the users themselves controlling who has access to their calendar/contacts/etc.

You can do this two ways:

1. Go the delegate route. Have the user go through Outlook, and add a delegate, the permissions are more granular and easier to set from the start.
2. Have the user go into their calendar, click on Share My Calendar, and choose the recipients. The recipient will get an email asking if they wish to participate in the shared calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know the common ways of setting this up. I was just wondering if there was a cmdlet or something to provide access that I was unaware of.

Comment: Your old admin was probably granting Full Mailbox access from the server, which is a big No-No.

Comment: What sort of no-no? Just curious. This was only an issue because he's a clinician where I work who never has a second to sit at his computer, let alone click through his outlook properties to grant someone access to edit it. He's the kinda guy who has his schedule made for him all day long. I'll just try to catch him at his desk and do it for him real quick.